# Summary remembers the previous 'garbage' values

Tags: r, summary, garbage, data-cleaning

I have a data with a column which mentions the gender of a person. Unfortunately there are few misplaced columns/erroneous values.

```
summary(data$gender)
```

gives something like

```
boy : 19232
girl : 14565
Maths : 3
Science : 4
... some 20 garbage values : 1
```

I wrote a code to replace values other than **boy, girl** to **error**. Now **summary(data$gender)** gives something like

```
boy : 19232
error : 156
girl : 14565
Maths : 0
Science : 0
... other garbage values : 0
```

Is there any way I can prevent printing values for which count is 0?

**Why I need this** - There are more than 100 columns. I am using a new flag column which is set to 1 when it encounters an "error" across any cell value, and in the end, I delete the records with flag=1. **I need to view a short summary of the entire data.**, something like

```
boy : 19232
error : 156
girl : 14565
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: likely you have a factor there and the levels are still present. remove the levels and try again. sharing some data would have been nice, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Comment: No. I have converted them to "error".

Answer (score 2):

The function you're looking for is probably `droplevels`, to drop out unused factor levels.

In your case

```
summary(droplevels(data)$gender)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
data = factor(c("girl","boy","girl","boy","math","girl","girl"), levels = c("girl", "boy", "math"))
> summary(data)
girl  boy math 
   4    2    1 
data2 = factor(c("girl","boy","girl","boy","math","girl","girl"), levels = c("girl", "boy", "math", "garbage"))
> summary(data2)
   girl     boy    math garbage 
      4       2       1       0 
> summary(droplevels(data2))
girl  boy math 
   4    2    1
```

In `data` everything is fine. But in `data2` there is another level that is not used and it enforces the 0 to be shown.

As @user295691 has pointed out first `droplevels` (see `?droplevels` for quick reference) will help you get rid of these error levels.

I repeat, you have a factor here and even if you set the values to something else the levels remain. The first decent explanation I could google might be [this link here.](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/factors.html)